# Unexpected result when applying the boolean theorems

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have this expression and have to simplify it : $\lnot B\,\lnot C + A \,\lnot B \, C$

What I did was: $\lnot B\,\lnot C + A \,\lnot B \, C = \ \lnot B(\lnot C + C + A) = \lnot B(1) = \lnot B$

Why isn't this simplification correct? First I applied the commutative property so that I could use the distributive as I had a $\lnot B$ on the both sides; then by complements, $\lnot C + C = 1$, and by identity $\lnot B(1) = \lnot B$. Supposedly, it's not right; what is the error?

Comment: You have written $¬B¬C+A¬BC= ¬B(¬C+C+A)$ but it is $¬B¬C+A¬BC= ¬B(¬C+CA)$

Comment: My bad sry the last C is not negated

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I understand my error now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the application of the distributive property:
$$\neg B\neg C + A \neg B C = \neg B (\neg C + A\cdot C).$$
Notice how your $+$ became a $\cdot$ in my version.

Comment: Yeah, forgot it stayed with the same signal, thanks!